# error boundary when using hooks to display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I try to get user data when load page using hooks(in case useEffect), but i got error said "Consider adding an error boundary to your tree" and my app getting blank.

my code looks similar like below

still configure out how to fix it, but i dont know how. coz i new using react

```
const [ProfileData, setProfileData] = useState({});
const [ownerId, setOwnerId] = useState('')

let ProfileID = 12

const getId = async () => {
      const responseData = await getUserData();
      setOwnerId(responseData.ID);
};
```

this is my function to get data from API

```
const getProfileData = () => {
        setLoading(true);

        getId();

        const jsonData = {
            ID: ProfileID,
            OwnerId: ownerId
        };

        const headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
        };

        try {
            axios
                .post(
                    config.API_SERVER + 'SearchProfile',
                    {
                        Data: jsonData ,
                    },
                    headers
                )
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.status == 'Success') {
                        setProfileData(response.data.Data);
                        setLoading(false);
                    } else {
                        setProfileData({});
                        alert(response.data.status);
                    }
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

this is my hooks

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const load = async () => {
            try {
                await getProfileData();
            } catch (err) {
                throw err
            }
        }

        load()
    }, []);
```

and this is my return to display data

```
return (
 <p>{ProfileData.Name}</p>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you throw an error (`throw err`) but you don't catch it, you can omit that part, pass the error message to state, or use [react-error-boundary](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary).

```
useEffect(() => {
  getProfileData();
}, []);
```